# bing map integration in iphone

Tags: ios, bing-maps, touchesbegan

I am trying to implement bing maps in iphone. I am able to show the map. But the problem is that whenever I try any interaction with the map, it crashes. Here's the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BMMapViewInternal touchesBegan:withEvent:inView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e777e0' 
any idea as to how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Check the read-me, section "Add Linker Flags":

```
- Set the value of the Other Linker Flags environment variable to -ObjC -all_load.
```